# how to fix "NoCredentialsError" with Boto3 for DynamoDB

Tags: ubuntu, flask, boto3

I'm currently creating a webapp using Flask and DynamoDB.

However, I ran into a really strange error currently that I hope someone might be able to assist me with.

Currently when I run the web app in Pycharm, everything works fine.
I'm able to request data from DynamoDB without any issues or errors.

However, the moment I run the exact same file on Ubuntu with Python3, I suddenly encounter a "NoCredentialsError".
The exact same file works fine when I run it on Pycharm, but for some reason it's giving me this error only when I try and test it in Ubuntu.

The function that's resulting in this error is simply this:

```
def selectItem(PK, SK):

    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name="us-east-1")
    
    table = dynamodb.Table('testDB')

    response = table.get_item(
        Key={
            'PK': PK,
            'SK': SK
        }
    )
    return response
```

I have the table and region coded in simply for the sake of context and to keep things simple while testing.

Here is the full Traceback for additional details:

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2095, in **call**
> return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2080, in wsgi_app
> response = self.handle_exception(e)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
> response = self.full_dispatch_request()

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
> rv = self.dispatch_request()

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
> return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)

> File "/mnt/c/Users/Test/Desktop/Coding/TestCode/mainapp/webapp.py", line 139, in login
> session["farm"] = DynamoDB.selectItem("Users", session["email"])

> File "/mnt/c/Users/Test/Desktop/Coding/TestCode/mainapp/DataBase/DynamoDB.py", line 147, in selectItem
> response = table.get_item(

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 580, in do_action
> response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 88, in **call**
> response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 415, in _api_call
> return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 731, in _make_api_call
> http, parsed_response = self._make_request(

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 751, in _make_request
> return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 107, in make_request
> return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 180, in _send_request
> request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 120, in create_request
> self._event_emitter.emit(event_name, request=request,

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 358, in emit
> return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 229, in emit
> return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 212, in _emit
> response = handler(**kwargs)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 95, in handler
> return self.sign(operation_name, request)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 167, in sign
> auth.add_auth(request)

> File "/home/testcode/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 401, in add_auth
> raise NoCredentialsError()
> botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you your aws credentials on your ubuntu machine?  It should be looking for them at `~/.aws/credentials`

Comment: Worked a charm! 
Thank you!

I didn't have awscli installed.

I installed awscli
Ran "pip3 install --upgrade awscli"

After the update I ran "aws configure", entered my credentialsm and now it works like a charm!

Thanks a bunch!!!!